# NodeJS server returning empty data from MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, post, get

I am making an app where the app is going to send the POST request data to the nodeJS server. The `JSON` format of the content looks like: `{"encrypteddata": "someencryptedvalueofthetext"}`. This data will be saved in a MongoDB.
I created two file one is `app.js` and another is `/models/encdata.js`. Content of both the file is given below.
**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

app.use(bodyParser.json());

ENCDATA = require('./models/encdata');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/encdata', { useMongoClient: true }); // the url access the database

var db = mongoose.connection;

app.get('/', function(req, res){

    res.send('Visit /api/encdata');

    app.get('/api/encdata', function(req, res){
    ENCDATA.getENCDATA(function(err, encdata){
            if(err){
                throw err;
            }
            res.json(encdata);
        });
    });

    app.post('/api/encdata', function(req, res){
        var encdata = req.body;
        ENCDATA.addENCDATA(encdata, function(err, encdata){
            if(err){
                throw err;
            }
            res.json(encdata);
        });
    });

 });

 app.listen(3000);
 console.log('Running on port 3000');
```

**encdata.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var encdataencryptSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    encrypteddata: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
});

var ENCDATA = module.exports = mongoose.model('encdata', encdataencryptSchema);

module.exports.getENCDATA = function(callback, limit){
    ENCDATA.find(callback).limit(limit);
}

module.exports.addENCDATA = function(encdata, callback){
    ENCDATA.create(encdata, callback);
}
```

And data in MongoDB is:

```
{"encrypteddata": "someencryptedvalueofthetext"}
```

But when I make a GET request to the url `localhost:3000/api/encdata` it shows `[]` (an empty array although I have data). Even the POST request is not working and I am not able to save any data.

Comment: You are not closing these braces: `app.get('/', function(req, res) {`

Comment: I am closing that and I am not getting any typo error like that.

Comment: But you are closing it after declare the other endpoints...

Comment: I tried that too and the problem is the same. However what I did is also gonna work.

Comment: Have you tried passing a `limit` to `ENCDATA.getENCDATA()` method?

Comment: I did that too. But its not working.

Comment: Try `ENCDATA.find().limit(limit).exec(callback);`

Comment: It didn't worked. The result is still the same.

Comment: are you querying the right collection?

Comment: yeah the collection name is encdata.

Comment: Check (console.log or something) if encdata methods are called and callback is called

Comment: Yes, everything is being called. I restarted everything but still its the same.

Comment: Try changing your `model` call to `mongoose.model('encdata', encdataencryptSchema, 'encdata')`. By default, the collection name is the _pluralization_ of the model name, which is likely `encdatas` here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rewrote your code by changing the name of the variable and it worked for me. The **app.js** file looks something like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var http = require('http');

app.use(bodyParser.json());

AES = require('./models/aes');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/aes', { useMongoClient: true }); //     the url access the database

var db = mongoose.connection;

app.get('/', function(req, res){

res.send('Visit /api/aes');

 app.get('/api/aes', function(req, res){
      AES.getAES(function(err, aes){
         if(err){
             throw err;
         }
         res.json(aes);
     });
 });

    app.post('/api/aes', function(req, res){
        var aes = req.body;
         AES.addAES(aes, function(err, aes){
             if(err){
                throw err;
            }
            res.json(aes);
        });
    });

});



app.listen(3000);
console.log('Running on port 3000');
```

In the **encdata.js** you can change the variable to `AES`. Name the *mongodb collection and database* as `aes`.

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me. But I cannot understand what was the problem in my code. Just by changing the variable how this can work.